# Make OledDBcoonection Where Microsoft Office 2010 is not installed

Tags: c#, excel

I am running the below code to make connection with Excel on **Development Machine**.It is working fine.

But What should I do to run this code on **Server** where Microsoft Office 2010 is not installed?
Is there any Dll to include in Project to run this code?

```
Filepath="C:\"


var ConStr= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+Filepath+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;\"";

    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr))
        {
        conn.Open();
}
```

Comment: I think it's called OpenXML that allows you to work with Excel files when Excel is not actually installed. I am pretty sure this has been asked plenty of times on Stack Overflow, why don't you search first?

Answer (score 1):

Just install the **Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010** (see link).

[Download - Microsoft Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

It will allow you to use the **Microsoft.ACE.OleDB - Provider**. More info about this database engine can be found on the website.

Comment: I have tried with this Microsoft Access Database Engine installation still the code is giving below error
The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: Normally the provider is installed using that database engine: Do you have a 32bit/ 64bit machine?

Comment: Did you install the x64 Database Engine? If Not did you target your solution to 32bit?